# Positive integers $k = p_{1}^{r_{1}} \cdots p_{n}^{r_{n}} > 1$ satisfying $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_{i}^{-r_{i}} < 1$

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

A divisor $d$ of $k = p_{1}^{r_{1}} \cdots p_{n}^{r_{n}}$ is *unitary* if and only if $d = p_{1}^{\varepsilon_{1}} \cdots p_{n}^{\varepsilon_{n}}$, where each exponent $\varepsilon_{i}$ is either $0$ or $r_{i}$. Let $D_{k} = ${ $d$ } be the subset of unitary divisors of an integer $k > 1$ satisfying $\omega(d) = \omega(k) - 1$.

**Definition**. A positive integer $k = p_{1}^{r_{1}} \cdots p_{n}^{r_{n}} > 1$ is *hyperbolic* if and only if $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_{i}^{-r_{i}} < 1$ or, equivalently, $\sum_{d \in D_{k}} d < k$.

See my [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A181629) entry.

For example, $3$, $10$ and $20$ are hyperbolic, but $30$ and $510510 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$ are not.

Assuming my calculations are correct, I'll state the following with some confidence:

Indeed, many positive integers are hyperbolic. Of the first $10^{8}$ integers, $70334760$ are hyperbolic. Non-trivial prime powers, squares or higher, are also hyperbolic. If $k$ is a hyperbolic integer, then so are its proper, non-trivial unitary divisors; however, the same cannot be inferred for all divisors (consider the hyperbolic integer $900$ and its non-hyperbolic divisor $30$). In fact, an arbitrary product of any number of non-trivial unitary divisors of a hyperbolic integer is again hyperbolic.

The set of hyperbolic integers is closed under *exponentiation*, but not under addition (e.g., $10 + 20 = 30$) or under multiplication (e.g., $3 \times 10 = 30$).

Define the *Prime zeta function*, $\zeta_{P}(s) = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} p^{-s}$, which converges absolutely for $\mathsf{Re}(s) > 1$. Recall that the multiplicity of a prime divisor $p$ of $k$ is the largest exponent $r$ such that $p^{r}$ divides $k$ but $p^{r+1}$ does not. If the minimum multiplicity of an integer $k$ is $2$ or greater, then $k$ is hyperbolic as can be seen by the elementary bound
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_{i}^{-r_{i}} < \zeta_{P}(2) \approx 0.452247 ....
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, the question of hyperbolicity is non-trivial only for integers with minimum multiplicity $1$.

Numerical evidence suggests that the natural density of the hyperbolic integers is greater than $0.988284 \dots$, and I conjecture that *almost all* integers are indeed hyperbolic (i.e., the natural density is 1).

**Question:** Is anything presently known about such integers? (References welcome!)

**Question:** Is there a simple proof showing (or refuting) that almost all integers are hyperbolic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Say $k$ has the prime factorization $p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_n^{r_n}$. Then let $H(k)$ be the "hyperbolicity" of this integer, $H(k) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{-r_i}$. Hyperbolic integers are those integers $k$ that have $H(k) < 1$.

Now, $H(k)$ for some "random" integer $k$ looks like a sum of independent random variables $X_p$, one for each prime $p$, where $P(X_p = p^{-k})$ is the probability that a random integer is divisible by $p^k$ but not $p^{k+1}$. Thus $P(X_p = p^{-k}) = (p-1)/p^{k+1}$.

In particular
$$ E(X_p) = \sum_{k \ge 1} p^{-k} P(X_p = p^{-k}) = \sum_{k \ge 1} {p-1 \over p^{2k+1}} = {1 \over p^2 + p} $$

Things get a bit tricky in finding the distribution of $\sum_p X_p$; in particular a central limit theorem won't work, because the contribution of each of the small primes is too large.  But there is some limiting distribution, and I suspect it at least bears some resemblance to the limiting distribution of the actual hyperbolicities of integers.

Incidentally, my tests seem to point to a natural density of hyperbolic integers somewhere in the neighborhood of 99 percent. I'd conjecture that integers with hyperbolicity less than $k$ have a natural density.  There are similar results on the distribution of $\sigma(n)/n$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$; see for example Marc Deleglise, [Bounds for the density of abundant integers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-7/issue-2/Bounds-for-the-density-of-abundant-integers/em/1048515661.full).

Comment: Thank you for reference! It's been quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

[[EDIT: Let $ k = p_1^{r_1} \cdots p_n^{r_n} $ as in your post. Then define the *hyperbolicity* $ H(k) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{-r_i} $.]]

We can refute the idea in your second question in a much more general manner than you might expect. Note that since $ \zeta_P(1) $ diverges, numbers can have arbitrarily large hyperbolicity; similarly, since $ H(2^n) = 2^{-n} $, it follows that numbers can have arbitrarily small hyperbolicity. Define $ d(x) $ to be the [asymptotic density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of natural numbers satisfying $ H(n) > x $. We will demonstrate the strict inequality $ d(x) > 0 $ holds for all $ x > 0 $, and even deduce a satisfying lower bound for sufficiently, erm... not-small $x $.

Fix $ x \in (0,\infty) $. Let $ k $ be the smallest natural number such that $ 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + \dots + 1/p_k > x $. Then for $ n = 2(3)(5)\cdots (p_k) $, $ H(n) > x $. Note that hyperbolicity, taken as an arithmetic function, is [multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), though not completely. In fact, by categorizing which prime factors belong where and when they're duplicated, one can see the following formula:

$$ H(ab) = H(a) + H(b) - H(\gcd(a,b)^2) + H(\gcd(a,b)) $$

This isn't necessary for our argument, I'm just putting that out there for posterity.

At any rate, we may conclude that for any number $ m $ which is coprime with $ n $, we can obtain another sufficently hyperbolic number via multiplication: $ H(nm) >
H(n) > x $. Note that the density of numbers coprime with $ n $ can be expressed as

$$ y = (1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/5)\cdots (1-1/p_k). $$

This formula echoes the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes): it follows from the fact that the probability a number is divisible by a prime is independent of the probability it is divisible by a different prime.

Finally, if you take the set of all numbers $ m $ coprime with $n $, and multiply them all by $ n $, they'll become $ n $ times more sparse, hence the density of all numbers of the form $ n m $ is $ y / n $. This proves $ d(x) \ge y/n $, which is a pretty good lower bound so long as $ x $ isn't too small (this is my subjective impression). For $ x = 1 $, as in your original question, we have the close lower bound $ (1/30)(1/2)(2/3)(4/5) $ or about 0.89%.

So far I haven't been able to determine whether or not there exists any $ \epsilon > 0 $ such that $ d(\epsilon) = 1 $. If there is one, then there would exist a maximum $ u $ such that $ d(\epsilon) = 1 $ for any $ \epsilon \in (0,u) $, which would make an interesting new constant. Note that $ d(x)$ is decreasing, though I'm not sure if it's continuous. What would *really* be interesting is if $ d(x) $ were differentiable on some interval.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer. Please do add more as you understand the problem better!

Comment: I don't believe that hyperbolic numbers have ever been systematically studied, so it would be of interest (to me at least) if a collaborative note could be written. I've got more on these objects. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: I'm interested in more on this concept. I'll add some more trivia I've gathered since posting into the above answer (I figured out how to prove $ d(x) $ never equals 1). One thing I don't get, though, is why you're focused in on $ x = 1 $; seems sort of arbitrary to me. Then again maybe you have some special facts about that case.

Comment: Numerical evidence suggested that it was greater than 0.988.... With the exception of a few nice examples, I've never seen an asymptotic density so close, but not equal to, 1.

Comment: If you consider the sets {2,3,5}, {2,3,7,11}, and {2,3,7,13} you get up to 0.973%.  It should not be hard to get this over 1%, but the inclusion-exclusion gets tricky.

Comment: Scratch that, I haven't proved $d(x) < 1$, I made an error. Note that almost-but-not-quite-1 asymptotic density is true for almost all $x$ here, not just $x=1$. Anyway I found a few other bits. Let $n=\prod p^r$ and $q=\prod p$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(n)n^{-s}=\zeta'(s)-\zeta(s)\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s(p^{s+1}-1)}$$ and $$\exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H(n^k)}{k}\right) = \frac{\phi(q)\sigma_1(n/q)}{n}$$

Comment: Also, based on my intuition I have a conjecture as to the moment generating function of $H$'s distribution. I essentially factor it into an Euler product: $$\mathbb{E}(e^{tH}) = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\left(1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty p^{-r} \exp(p^{-r} t) \right). $$ This is remarkably eerie, is it not?

Comment: @anon: This problem is starting to turn into beautiful mathematics.

Comment: By the way this problem stems from some of my work in singularity theory and 2-dim QFT models on the space-time torus.